# Underscore function to generate an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

It is kind of newbie question because I have never used Underscore library. I have to generate an array, which would have number values. Here is code using for loop.

```
for (var traverse = 0; traverse <= 900; traverse += 25) {
  topToDown.push(traverse);

  if (buffer[i].start === traverse) {
    traverse += buffer[i].height - 25;
    if (i < buffer.length - 1) {
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

i initializes from 0. Now this looks pretty messy to me and I want to use underscore here to make it a little beautiful. The problem is I have never used it, so I am staring at its documentation for a while, but not getting anywhere meaningful.

Comment: What are `topToDown`, `buffer` and `i`?

Comment: I am not sure you actually need underscore / lodash to make your code better. You need to explain a bit what are you trying to achieve, this will probably help a lot to help you.

Comment: Why is Underscore a factor here?

Comment: `topToDown` is an empty in which the values need to be pushed. `buffer` is an array of objects, which has a height `property`, and a start `property`. I'm using `i` just for accessing different elements in the buffer array. End result would be
topToDown is something like [25, 50, 75, 100, 275, 300, 325, 450, ... , 900]
Where `buffer[0].start` is 100 and `buffer[1].start` is 325

Comment: @tadman I felt like underscore can help me in this case and it is already installed in my project.

Comment: You need to better describe what you're doing in terms of input and output.

Comment: @tadman Okay I want to populate this `topToDown` array with numbers 25 to 900, so I know I'll use `_.range()` for that but I want to exclude certain numbers from `topToDown`. The numbers I want to exclude depend on `buffer.start` property, so when my loop encounters `buffer.start` to be equal to transversal, it should push `transversal` to `topToDown` array and then skip numbers till buffer's height so I add buffer.height to it. Loop resumes and same thing happens but now to the next element in the buffer array, so `i` for iterating through elements of `buffer`(which is an array of objects)

Comment: @Sanchit Put the explanation in the question itself. It would also help if you showed sample input and expected results (use a smaller range than 900 for the example).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.from` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

E.g:

```
const arr = Array.from({length: 20}, (i) => Math.random());
```

This populates the array with values in the function.

Comment: Nice idea, but what my basic problem is that I want to populate the array but by excluding some values. What I want to exclude is based upon the properties of `buffer` array. Can I use `filter()` here?

Comment: If you have an existing array, then yes, `filter` would be how you filter it. The `array.from` bit doesn't really work if you don't know the final size of your array.